# How to change createTextNode value using switch

Tags: javascript

From web api i get weather condition and that condition i want to change to icon.
Right now it prints condition - "clear" for example. I want to change clear to icon.

```
let oras = document.createTextNode(weathers.forecastTimestamps[i].conditionCode);
col1.appendChild(oras);
```

with this one i append my variable oras to column so i get printed out everything is ok.
but when i try to switch nothing changes i tried at first to translate it

```
                    switch (oras) {
                    case "clear":
                    oras = "Giedra";
                        /*let icon = createElement('i');
                        icon.classList.add("fas","fa sun");
                        icon.appendChild(col1);*/
                        break;
                    case 'sunny':
                    oras = "Sauleta";
                    break;
                }
```

But nothing happend, no errors

```
https://pastebin.com/nqBHT8Gd
```

Heres a full code code starts from function weather
I was trying to solve it for a past hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing `oras` after its value is inserted into the DOM which is too late. It has to be done before:

```js
let oras;

switch (weathers.forecastTimestamps[i].conditionCode) {
  case "clear":
    oras = "Giedra";
    /*let icon = createElement('i');
    icon.classList.add("fas","fa sun");
    icon.appendChild(col1);*/
    break;
  case 'sunny':
    oras = "Sauleta";
    break;
}

col1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oras));
```

Comment: thank youu, what is correct way  to add icon in let oras?

Comment: @Justas.P `oras` is just a *string*. If you want to ad icon to it, it has to be at least `span`. You can also just append an icon to `col1`.